# How to change the Flutter TextButton height?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This is the output:

[image]

1. I try to make an app but when I use the `TextButton`, I get the space between two Buttons
2. I need one by one without space
3. If I use the `Expanded` Widget, `ScrollChildView` doesn't work
4. I try but I can't clear this stuff.
5. I try to make this type of `TextButton`.

Anyone know or have any idea about this?

```
    import "package:flutter/material.dart";
    import 'package:audioplayers/audio_cache.dart';

    class Account extends StatefulWidget {
    Account({Key key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _AccountState createState() => _AccountState();
    }

    class _AccountState extends State<Account> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    TextButton(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'One',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final player = AudioCache();
                        player.play('note1.wav');
                      },
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 1,
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Two',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final player = AudioCache();
                        player.play('note2.wav');
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Three',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final player = AudioCache();
                        player.play('note3.wav');
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Four',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.grey),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final player = AudioCache();
                        player.play('note4.wav');
                      },
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          'Five',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        final player = AudioCache();
                        player.play('note5.wav');
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    }

     }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the following to even add your preferred size as well

N/B: child sized box is the main child widget inside Padding widget

```
Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                      child: SizedBox(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 200,
                        child: ElevatedButton.icon(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => RegistrationMenu()));
                          },
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor:
                                MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red.shade800),
                          ),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person_add_alt_1_rounded, size: 18),
                          label: Text("Register Users"),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Thanks alot, SizedBox worked fine for me. it saves my time...

Answer (score 41):

You just wrap your text button with the `SizedBox` and set height and width as follows:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 30,
  width: 150,
  child: TextButton(...),
)
```

Answer (score 13):

- **Full available height:**

  ```dart
  SizedBox(
    height: double.infinity, // <-- match_parent
    child: TextButton(...)
  )
  ```
- **Specific height:**

  ```dart
  SizedBox(
    height: 100, // <-- Your height
    child: TextButton(...)
  )
  ```

Answer (score 11):

In Flutter 2.0, you can set the height of the `TextButton` directly without depending on other widgets by changing the `ButtonStyle.fixedSize`:

```
TextButton(
  child: Text('Text Button'),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size.fromHeight(150)),
),
```

If you want to modify all `TextButton`s, put it in the `ThemeData` like below:

```
return MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size.fromHeight(150)),
    ),
  ),
```

### [Live Demo](https://dartpad.dev/?id=490c9e09c2ff8deda24d8696e790c332&null_safety=true)

Comment: Not sure why, but this didn't have any effect on my buttons. I can see it works fine in the demo, so it might be something locally. Not sure what/why though.

Comment: This helped me to change height of all my buttons at once. Thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the TextButton in an "Expanded" Widget.

```
          Expanded(
            child: TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              ),
              child: const Text(''),
              onPressed: () {
                playSound(1);
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be wrapping with `ConstrainedBox` and using `minWidth` & `minHeight`

properties.

---

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints:BoxConstraints(
    minHeight:80,
    minWidth:200
    ),
  child:TextButton(..)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

1. Determine text button height using

> Sizedbox

2. Remove padding around text button using

> TextStyle.StyleFrom()

```
SizedBox(
  height: 24.0,        
  child: TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('See more'),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero, 
    ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

TextButton(
 onPressed: _submitOrder,
 child: Padding(
     padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
     child: Text("Raise")),
 style: ButtonStyle(
   shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
   const RoundedRectangleBorder(
   borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
   side: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)))),
)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap
  ),
  child: Text(''),
);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31562547)