# how to decrease textbutton height Flutter

Tags: flutter

How can I decrease the height of the text button? If I force a small height for him it works. But I want the height to be just the height of the text letter. It is possible? I tried wrapping it in an Expanded but it doesn't work.

```dart
Container(
            color: Colors.amberAccent[100],
            child: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: const Text('Visualizar',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              ),
            ),
          )
```

as it is now in the code:

[image]

How I want it to look:

[image]

Comment: **This link will help to you** [How to change the Flutter TextButton height?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68967516/9719695)

Answer (score 2):

You can create simple custom buttons with `InkWell`. This way its height is same as your `Text` widget's height.

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomButton({super.key, required this.child, required this.onPressed});

  final Widget child;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: onPressed,
      child: child,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the width & height of textbutton as follows

```
TextButton(
            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                fixedSize: const Size(300, 100),
                foregroundColor: Colors.red,
                backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('TextButton width & height'),
          ),
```

or just set height only like this

```
TextButton(
  child: Text('Text Button'),
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(fixedSize: Size.fromHeight(350)),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also wrap your TextButton with a fixed height/width SizedBox/Container

Container example:

```
Container(
        height: 20.0, // whatever height you wanna give
        width: 80.0,  // whatever width you wanna give
        color: Colors.amberAccent[100],
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('Visualizar',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

SizedBox(It doesn't have the color argument, that's why I removed it from the below code) example:

```
SizedBox(
        height: 20.0, // whatever height you wanna give
        width: 80.0,  // whatever width you wanna give
        child: TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text('Visualizar',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          style: TextButton.styleFrom(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Use the **visualDensity** property and/or **tapTargetSize** property for this.

Referring to your example:

```
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.compact,
    tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  ),
  child: const Text(
     'Visualizar',
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
   ),
),
```

### Explanation

The Flutter Material Documentation writes about this:

### [VisualDensity class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VisualDensity-class.html)

> Defines the visual density of user interface components.
>
> Density, in the context of a UI, is the vertical and horizontal
> "compactness" of the components in the UI. It is unitless, since it
> means different things to different UI components.
>
> [...]
>
> For example, for buttons, it affects the spacing around the child of the button. [...]

### [tapTargetSize property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ButtonStyle/tapTargetSize.html)

> Configures the minimum size of the area within which the button may be
> pressed.
>
> If the tapTargetSize is larger than minimumSize, the button will
> include a transparent margin that responds to taps.